# Why is underline red in jsp and how to iterate list correctly

Tags: java, list, jsp

I don't understand what I do wrong.
I'd like to iterate list in jsp. (In class it's working)

```
        public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException {
    List<SprawdzanieCen> PaS = SprawdzanieCenLista.PS();

    for (SprawdzanieCen ob : PaS ) {
        System.out.println("nrFaktury: "+ob.nrFaktury);
    }
}
```

But as I wrote I'd like to do it in jsp
jsp code is as follows:

```
        <% 
out.println("Lets Start");
List<SprawdzanieCen> PaS = SprawdzanieCenLista.PS();
for (SprawdzanieCen s : PaS) {
    s.nrFaktury;
} 
%>
```

I do not understand why "nrFaktury" is underline on red. Hot to iterate this list.
Help,

Comment: for everything, the best way is to keep Java code out of your jsp file

Comment: Use JSTL and just use expression language

Comment: that said, `s.nrFaktury;` is invalid java - this is not specific to JSP, it also doesn't compile in a regular *.java - file

Answer (score 1):

```
<% 
    out.println("Lets Start");
    List<SprawdzanieCen> PaS = SprawdzanieCenLista.PS();
    for (SprawdzanieCen s : PaS) {
        out.println(s.nrFaktury);
    } 
%>
```

You need to print the s.nrFaktury, without the print statement, the line will contain a syntax error.